# Why can't gradle run javafx application correctly?

Tags: java, gradle, javafx

I downloaded the javafx sdk, in the gradle settings I specified the path to the sdk as a local repository. Configured the compilation and launch plugin in the build gradle file.

```
plugins {
  id 'application'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
flatDir{
    dirs 'C:/Users/insec/Desktop/javafx-sdk-17.0.1/lib'
  }
}

dependencies{
  implementation files ('javafx.base.jar')
  implementation files ('javafx.controls.jar')
}

application {
  mainModule = 'piglet.friend'
  mainClass = 'piglet.friend.Main'
}

ext.moduleName = 'piglet.friend'

String modulePath = 'C:\\Users\\insec\\Desktop\\javafx-sdk-17.0.1\\lib'

compileJava {
   sourceCompatibility = '17'
   targetCompatibility = '17'
   inputs.property("moduleName", moduleName)
   doFirst {
     options.compilerArgs = [
            '--module-path', modulePath,
            '--add-modules', 'javafx.controls'
     ]
     classpath = files()
   }
}

plugins.withType(JavaPlugin).configureEach {
  java {
    modularity.inferModulePath = true
  }
}
run {
/* inputs.property("moduleName", moduleName)*/
doFirst {
    jvmArgs = [
            '--module-path', modulePath,
            '--add-modules', 'javafx.controls'
              ]
        }
}

jar {
    manifest {
      attributes 'Main-Class': 'piglet.friend.Main'
    }
}
```

I was able to assemble a jar file, and was able to run it by specifying the path to javafx modules at startup. (Working code)

```
java -jar --module-path C:\Users\insec\Desktop\javafx-sdk-17.0.1\lib --add-modules javafx.controls piglet.jar
```

But there are some problems.
I can't run the program through the run task in gradle. At the output, I get information that the module has not been found.
I tried to study which commands the run task executes.

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.1\bin\java.exe --module-path 
C:\Users\insec\Desktop\javafx-sdk-17.0.1\lib --add-modules 
javafx.controls -Dfile.encoding=windows-1251 -Duser.country=RU - 
Duser.language=ru -Duser.variant --module-path 
C:\Users\insec\Desktop\piglet\build\libs\piglet.jar --module 
piglet.friend/piglet.friend.Main

Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Error reading module: 
C:\Users\insec\Desktop\piglet\build\libs\piglet.jar
Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: 
Package piglet not found in module :run (Thread[Execution worker 
for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.078 secs.
```

In general, it does the same thing, the same path to modules, the same modules.

When developing a project in Intellij, she generally does not see javafx modules (although gradle can build a jar, and I can run it from the console).

I tried to add javafx sdk as a dependency in Intellij. **Project structure -> Libraries ->**. It works. But as soon as I update gradle via Intellij, it removes this dependency for some reason and the whole project starts glowing red.

Also when trying to connect a library from a remote repository

```
implementation group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.9'
```

I can no longer assemble a jar file with the error "module not found".

My file **module-info.java**

```
module piglet.friend{
   requires javafx.controls;
   requires com.google.gson;

   opens piglet;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using the Gradle plugin? https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#gradle

Comment: @FranciscoMateo I want to learn how to build a project without a post-root plugin.